# While loop condition strange behavior php

Tags: php, while-loop

Can someone please explain what is the difference between the first loop and the second, why the first works normal and the second ignores the condition?
The only thing I change is that instead of raising the value directly on the $i variable I am raising through $q variable(caution the second loop is infinite)

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < 10) {
    $i++;
}
```

```
$i = 0;
$q =  $i;
while ($q < 10) {
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: When you do `$q =  $i`, you are just assigning the value.  It's not a reference, so if you echo `$q` inside the loop, you will see it never changes.

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: They are different variables, why do you think in the second code that changing `$i` will update `$j`?

Comment: Can you please elaborate, It seems logical to me that the first will change the second and the second will affect other things accordingly

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to say with that comment, in the second code, `$q` will stay as 0, you can see in the loop that `$i` will change.  The only link between the two variables is that you set `$q = $i` before the loop, thats all that happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$i = 0;
$q = $i;

// $q is now equals to $i, but it is not
// a reference, it only has the value of $i
// at this specific moment.

while ($q < 10) {
    // $i == 0
    // $q == 0

    $i++;

    // $i == 1
    // $q == 0
}
```

`$q` will be 0 forever since you don't increment it, so `$q < 10` is always `true`.

However in your first loop:

```php
$i = 0;
while ($i < 10) {
    // $i == 0
    $i++;
    // $i == 1
}
```

At the tenth iteration, `$i < 10` becomes `false` and the loop stops.